# Joining strings of different lengths in a loop

Tags: python

I'm working on transforming a file from this format:

```
# SampleNamea   seq1a   seq2a
# SampleNameb   seq1b   seq2b
# SampleNamec   seq1c   seq2c
# SampelNamed   seq1d   seq2d
```

To this format:

```
# SampleNamea   SampleNameb 0   0   0   0   s   s   e   e   q   q   1   1   a   b   s   s   e   e   q   q   2   2   a   b
# SampleNamec   SampleNamed 0   0   0   0   s   s   e   e   q   q   1   1   c   d   s   s   e   e   q   q   2   2   c   d
```

Currently the script I have works if the `seq1a`, `seq1b`, etc are the same length. But in the dataset I have the length of the strings vary. If I try to run the script on my dataset, I get the message `IndexError: string index out of range`.

This is the portion of the script that: figures out the length of the string (i.e. `seq1aseq2a`, `seq1bseq2b`) that was append into the `InputMasterList`, adds the `SampleName`s with the extra zero's to the `OutputMasterList`. Then it is supposed to append to `OutputMasterList` the strings by selecting each consecutive element starting with element[0] from the `InputMasterList[LineEven]` string (`seq1aseq2a`) and `InputMasterList[LineOdd]` string (`seq1bseq2b`) and grouping them together into `OutputMasterList`. So the results would be (`s s e e q q 1 1 a b s s e e q q 2 2 a b`).

How can I get this script to work on different string lengths?

```
LineEven = 0
LineOdd = 1
RecordNum = 1

while RecordNum < (NumofLinesInFile/2):
    for i in range(len(InputMasterList[LineEven])):
        if i == 0:
            OutputMasterList.append(SampleList[LineEven]+'\t'+ SampleList[LineEven]+'\t'+'0'+'\t'+'0'+'\t'+'0'+'\t'+'0'+'\t')
        OutputMasterList[RecordNum] = InputMasterList[LineEven][i]+'\t'+InputMasterList[LineOdd][i]+'\t'
    RecordNum = RecordNum + 1
    LineEven = LineEven + 2
    LineOdd = LineOdd + 2
```

I am very much a beginner so I know this code is quite cumbersome, but any help would be appreciated. If you need clarification about what I'm attempting to do with this script please don't hesitate to ask.

***Update:*** Thank you for your prompt responses. Due to your feedback I realized that I had to change the nature of my question. In my dataset I have missing sequences that my script does not like and I need to account for this missing data with a placeholder which would be the same length as its counterpart.

Old format:

```
# SampleNamea   seq1a   seq2a

# SampleNameb   '.'      seq2b
```

New format:

```
# SampleNamea   seq1a   seq2a

# SampleNameb   NNNNN   seq2b
```

Then I believe my script will work!

**TL;DR** - Based on your feedback I have a basis on what my next steps should be.

Comment: Could you make sure your indentation is correct? Right now there's an infinite loop since `RecordNum` isn't incremented inside of the while loop

Comment: Your example does not make clear how the formats are being changed. Please give a verbal description of the new format from the old.

Comment: In case of seq1asequence2a, where lengths are different, how would like the output to be?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe and/or show what you want to the results to be when the two sequences are _not_ the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InputMasterList[LineOdd] string might look like (.seq2b)  as per your new update.

Then before before proceeding to append, do a check on InputMasterList

```
if '.' in InputMasterList[LineOdd]:
    InputMasterList[LineOdd] = InputMasterList[LineOdd].replace('.', 'NNNNN', 1)
```

You can do this for both LineOdd and LineEven

**Note**: This is based on your new input